# Why pipe a variable into Set-Item?

Tags: powershell, iis

I am trying to understand why `$appPool | Set-Item` is used below:

```
Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green "Creating application pool $PoolName"

$appPool = New-WebAppPool -Name $PoolName
$appPool.ManagedRuntimeVersion = $RuntimeVersion
$appPool.ManagedPipelineMode = $PipelineMode
$appPool.ProcessModel.IdentityType = $Identity

$appPool | Set-Item
```

What would happen when this line is missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those parameters are not available to the `New-WebAppPool` cmdlet directly according to the [help for the cmdlet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee790585.aspx). After setting the values for the properties in the variable object, piping it to `Set-Item` makes the call to the [Web Administration (IIS) Provider for Windows PowerShell](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee909471(v=ws.10).aspx) to register the settings in IIS.

Answer (score 3):

From [Technet Documentation of Set-Item:](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849797.aspx)  Changes the value of an item to the value specified in the command.

So in your case, command `$appPool | Set-Item` is actually going to set the properties you have defined so far.

With the command line `$appPool.ProcessModel.IdentityType = $Identity`; you are just defining the `IdentityType` property but it's actually not set yet; which will happen when `Set-Item` command invokes.

With `|` you are passing all the parameters you have defined as an argument to the `Set-Item` comandlet.